# how to check existed university name in mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```js
router.post('/university',function(req,res,next){
 University.create(req.body).then(function(detail){
 res.send(detail);
 });
});
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UniversitySchema = new Schema({
 university_name: {
  type:String
 },
 status: {
  type: String, enum: ['active', 'inactive']
 }

});



const University = mongoose.model('university',UniversitySchema);
module.exports = University;
```

how to check existed university name and insert new university to MongoDB database if does not exist. How to do this . Please do help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findOne` for this. If university already exist, do something you need, if university not exist then save this:

```
University.findOne({
    university_name: req.body.university_name
}, function(err, data) {
    if (data) {
        // output university or do something else
    } else {
        // save new university to collection
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can consider using [`upsert` option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), which means if the record already exists, update its information. If it does not, insert a new one into the database.

It's more optimized than executing a `findOne()`, followed by one more update operation.